# Include static library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glfw

I am in the process of learning C++. One of the most confusing things is to learn how to link libraries when using CMake (I use **CLion** on **Windows** which uses **CMake**). I downloaded the the pre-built binaries for GLFW from [here](http://www.glfw.org/download.html). I grabbed the includes folder and the library folder built with mingw. I places the necessary files in a dependencies folder in my project. My folder structure looks like this.

**Folder Structure**

```
Project
├── bin
├── build
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── dependencies
    │   └── GLFW
    │       ├── include
    │       │   └── GLFW
    │       │       ├── glfw3.h
    │       │       └── glfw3native.h
    │       └── lib
    │           └── libglfw3.a
    ├── lib
    └── main.cpp
```

**Code:** (Starter code pulled from GLFW Documentation [here](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html))

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**CmakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

target_include_directories(dependencies/GLFW/include)

add_executable(cmake main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cmake dependencies/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a)
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\181.4668.70\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\username\CLionProjects\cmake\src
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Failed to reload]
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong. In my search I came across some information that said I shouldn't be using older cmake functions like add_compiler_options, include_directories, link_directories, link_libraries.

**Updated CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(cmake main.cpp)

target_include_directories(cmake PRIVATE dependencies/GLFW/include)
target_link_libraries(cmake ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a)
```

**New Build Error**

```
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldependencies/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmake.dir\build.make:97: C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/bin/cmake.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: cmake] Error 2
```

**Reference Error**

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\181.4668.70\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\username\CLionProjects\cmake\Build --target cmake -- -j 8
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable C:\Users\username\CLionProjects\cmake\src\bin\cmake.exe
CMakeFiles\cmake.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `__imp_glClear'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmake.dir\build.make:98: C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/bin/cmake.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: cmake] Error 2
```

Comment: Your `target_include_directories` needs the name of the actual target (i.e. `target_include_directories(cmake dependencies/GLFW/include)`). The rest [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994427/1106415).

Comment: @hlt When I do that I get the following error. CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "cmake" which is not built by
  this project

Comment: Your reference errors are just because of the linker still not being able to link your library so they are just one error. With the updated `CMakeLists.txt`, I would have expected it to work. Does the library file actually exist in the directory that you have shown??

Comment: @AmitSingh yes that file does exist I pushed the source code to a public github repository located https://github.com/dblock247/cmake

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Windows build environment at the moment.

Comment: @AmitSingh well actually I am doing two clone of the project. One on windows to learn with that tool chain and one on that mac that should work with Unix/Linux. I have a repository for the mac version here --> https://github.com/dblock247/cmake-mac. I use LLVM/Clang 6 along with cmake on mac.

Comment: I made a Windows virtual environment and installed CMake and MinGW64. I don't get the linking error. I only get undefined reference errors. This means that there is no problem in the `CMakeLists.txt` any more. Your library file `libglfw3.a` is not proper.

Comment: @AmitSingh I too am getting those same errors. Regarding the library I downloaded them directly from GLFW.org as prebuilt binaries.

Comment: @AmitSingh your right I am resolving this question and Ill open another for the undefined reference issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that you have not supplied correct number of arguments to the `target_include_directories` function. Please refer to the syntax of `target_include_directories` in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/target_include_directories.html).

> target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [BEFORE]
>   <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]   [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>
>   [items2...] ...])

The arguments in angular brackets like `<target>` are required and the ones in square brackets like `[BEFORE]` are optional.

In your example the name of the target is `cmake` and hence the include command should look like

```
target_include_directories(cmake PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/GLFW/include")
```

You can read about [`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html).

Comment: That results in this error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "cmake" which is not built by
  this project

Comment: @Dblock247: You need to create a target before use it. That is, `add_executable()` call should come before `target_include_directories()` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that combined with adding PRIVATE fixed the cmake error but I get the following build error. In the next comment.

Comment: C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldependencies/GLFW/lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmake.dir\build.make:97: C:/Users/username/CLionProjects/cmake/src/bin/cmake.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: cmake] Error 2

Comment: @Dblock247: Comments are badly suited for multiline error messages. Instead, update your question post with a new code and new error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok will do.

Comment: @Tsyvarev please see updated original question above.

Comment: You should specify a library **file** for `target_link_libraries`, not a *directory* (`dependencies/GLFW/lib`). It was correct in your original question, why do you change that?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I got the error and was trying some things to fix it and I forgot to change it back before I posted. Either way with that adjustment I get the same error. I updated the question again.

Comment: @Dblock247: Also, in `target_link_libraries` you need to specify **absolute path** to the library. *Relative paths* work incorrectly. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) for that command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for all your help that got me one step closer. Now I seem to be getting undefined references errors. Please the updated question above.